# trackJS XML Parsing Error: no element found in firefox

Tags: javascript, xml, trackjs

I have implemented trackJS library for better debugging and logging. But whenever I send any error to trackJS it throws error only in Firefox. `XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: https://capture.trackjs.com/capture?token=<tokenid>
Line Number 1, Column 1:`

here's the code I am using to push errors to trackJS.

```
trackJs.console.error('some error msg.');
```

please let me know if I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: This is a harmless bug that's been present in Firefox for years: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=884693

Answer (score 0):

This is a old Firefox bug, there is no need to return a payload from the TrackJS error capture API, so we do not. The warning shown in the Firefox console is local-only. It can safely be ignored.